# Why doesn't width/height work with non positioned pseudo elements?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to set a **width** of **::before** pseudo-element to 80%. If I use positioning then everything works, but if I don't use it then everything fails.

Could you explain me why percentage width doesn't work without positioning? If you can please add some references to the specification

```css
.positioned {
    position: relative;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.positioned::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    background: red;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
}

.not-positioned {
    height: 15px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.not-positioned::before {
    content: "";
    background: red;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="positioned"></div>
<div class="not-positioned"></div>
```

Comment: width/height doesn't work on inline element and making the element positionned will make it a block element

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks, it's what I needed. You may add your answer so I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it's not about percentage values. You will have the same result even with pixel values and both width and height aren't working.

Pseudo elements are **inline** elements and their width/height is only defined by their content and the width/height set with CSS will be ignored.

> In CSS, `::before` creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the selected element. It is often used to add cosmetic content to an element with the content property. **It is inline by default.** <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)</sup>

> width
>
> This property **does not apply to non-replaced inline elements**. The content width of a non-replaced inline element's boxes is that of **the rendered content within them** <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property)</sup>

> The 'height' property does not apply. The height of the content area should be based on the font ... <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced)</sup>

---

By making the pseudo element `position:absolute` you will now consider the rules that applies to [Absolutely positioned element](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width) in order to calculate width and height. You will also notice that the element will have a computed value of `block` within display.

[image]

You should also pay attention to the use of *positioned element* which means either relative, absolute, fixed or sticky BUT making the element `position:relative` will keep it an inline level element and you still cannot use width/height.

```css
.positioned {
    position: relative;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.positioned::before {
    position: relative;
    content: "";
    background: red;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
}

.not-positioned {
    height: 15px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.not-positioned::before {
    content: "";
    background: red;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="positioned"></div>
<div class="not-positioned"></div>
```

This said, you can simplify you code by considering gradient if you want to achieve the same visual:

```css
.positioned {
  position: relative;
  height: 15px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(red,red) left/80% 100% no-repeat,
   aquamarine;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="positioned"></div>
```